# Euler and minus sign

Tags: math-mode, optional-arguments

I'm trying to define a macro to typeset Eulers complex e-power with or without a minus sign in its argument. I would like the macro to automatically detect if its argument starts with a `-`. I have the following MWE which uses and optional argument:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}

\def\imaginaryunit{j}                  % the imaginary unit, i for mathematician and theoretical physicist, j for the rest of the world.
\def\imunit{\mathrm{\imaginaryunit}}   % ... in upright math
\def\ce{\mathrm{e}}                    % the constant e, upright of course
\makeatletter
\def\epowim{\@ifnextchar[{\epowimi}{\epowimi[]}}       % e to-the-power-of imaginary unit
\def\epowimi[#1]#2{\ce^{#1\if\imaginaryunit j\relax\,\fi\imunit#2}}       % e to-the-power-of imaginary unit
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\epowim{\alpha}\qquad \epowim[-]{\alpha} \qquad \ce^{-\imunit\alpha}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

So I would like a macro that detects if its argument starts with a `-`:

```
\epowim{-\alpha}
```

should detect the `-` and place it before the imaginary unit instead of placing it after the imaginary unit.

So the question is if it can be done and how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}
\def\imaginaryunit{j}                  % the imaginary unit, i for mathematician and theoretical physicist, j for the rest of the world.
\def\imunit{\mathrm{\imaginaryunit}}   % ... in upright math
\def\ce{\mathrm{e}}                    % the constant e, upright of course
\newcommand\epowim[1]{\ce^{\epowimaux#1\relax\endep}}
\def\epowimaux#1#2\endep{\ifx-#1\relax-\imunit\else%
  \if j\imaginaryunit\relax\,\fi\imunit#1\fi#2}
\begin{document}
\[
\epowim{\alpha}\qquad \epowim{-\alpha} \qquad \ce^{-\imunit\alpha}
\]
\[
\epowim{x+t}\quad\epowim{-x+t}\quad\epowim{-}\quad\epowim{}
\]
\def\imaginaryunit{i}
\[
\epowim{\alpha}\qquad \epowim{-\alpha} \qquad \ce^{-\imunit\alpha}
\]
\[
\epowim{x+t}\quad\epowim{-x+t}\quad\epowim{-}\quad\epowim{}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i need. I changed the definition to `\def\epowimaux#1#2\endep{\ifx-#1\relax-\imunit\else\if\imaginaryunit j\relax\,\fi\imunit#1\fi#2}` to compensate for the fact that the j is too close to the e but not when using i as imaginary unit

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw Thanks.  And feel free to adapt to your need.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw I might only suggest using `\if j\imaginaryunit` rather than `\if\imaginaryunit j`.  Or better still, `\expandafter\ifx\imaginaryunit j`

Comment: I see nothing wrong in `\if\imaginaryunit j`, provided `\imaginaryunit` is either `i` or `j`. Oh, and did you try `\epowim{-}`? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I detect no problems with `\epowim{-}`.  As to the `\if` test, you are right if the choices are always `i` or `j`.  But users have a tendency to do strange stuff, like something that expands to `i` or `j`, or a different letter or symbol altogether, etc.  I was trying to head off crazy stuff.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I'm sorry to say that your solution fails with an empty argument, i.e.. `$\epowim{}$`

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw I stealth-edited the answer 8 hours ago to fix that case.  Try the MWE listed in the answer.  (an extra `\relax` was needed in the `\epowim` macro.

Comment: Notices that -;)

Answer (score 6):

Avoid `\def`, your life will be easier.

Since you seem to know about `\@ifnextchar`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}

% the imaginary unit, j for engineers and i for the rest of the world
\newcommand\imaginaryunit{j}
% in upright type as engineers do; also Euler's constant
\newcommand\imunit{\mathrm{\imaginaryunit}}
\newcommand\ce{\mathrm{e}}

\newcommand{\fiximunit}{\if\imaginaryunit j\,\fi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\epowim}[1]{\ce^{\epowim@#1}}
\newcommand{\epowim@}{\@ifnextchar-{\epowim@@}{\epowim@@{\fiximunit}}}
\newcommand{\epowim@@}[1]{#1\imunit}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\epowim{\alpha}\qquad \epowim{-\alpha} \qquad \ce^{-\imunit\alpha}
\qquad \epowim{} \qquad \epowim{-}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `\@ifnextchar-` uses the next argument if `-` is found, the successive one otherwise, but *without* removing `-`. So if `-` is called the result will be

```
\epowim@@-\alpha
```

which passes `-` as argument to `\epowim@@`. Otherwise `\epowim@@` is called with `\fiximunit` as argument.

This would not fail with `\epowim{}` or `\epowim{-}` to typeset e<sup>j</sup> and e<sup>−j</sup> respectively.

A perhaps simpler implementation with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

% the imaginary unit, j for engineers and i for the rest of the world
\newcommand\imaginaryunit{j}
% in upright type as engineers do; also Euler's constant
\newcommand\imunit{\mathrm{\imaginaryunit}}
\newcommand\ce{\mathrm{e}}

\newcommand{\fiximunit}{\if\imaginaryunit j\,\fi}

\NewDocumentCommand{\epowim}{m}{\ce^{\powim#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\powim}{t-}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{-\imunit}{\fiximunit\imunit}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\epowim{\alpha}\qquad \epowim{-\alpha} \qquad \ce^{-\imunit\alpha}
\qquad \epowim{} \qquad \epowim{-}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Nice comment too about mathematicians and all that...

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw You provoked me. `;-)`

Comment: Yes, I did... ;-)